# Application server for Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, deployment, oracle10g

I have to prepare an application server for deployment of an application implemented in Oracle 10g forms. The server which i will using is Sun Blade X6270 M3. Now the issue is that on my asking from developer (who happens to be a total jerk) that which application server should i be using, he said any which ever you like. 
All i am aware about application is that it will be available via url.
Honestly, i am confused here, please assist me in selecting the application server for an application developed in Oracle 10g forms. I don't to waste my time by installing a wrong application server and i also cannot ask developer to guide me. 
Thus seeking your help. A link to download the server would really assist me and please do mention if it is freeware or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need OracleAS Forms Services to run Forms.  With Forms 10g that means Oracle Application Server.  For Forms 11g (and later) that means Oracle WebLogic Server.